# Are any rockets currently in use capable of putting a man on the Moon?

Tags: rockets, the-moon, crewed-spaceflight, apollo-program, lunar-landing

Apollo 11 used the Saturn V rocket, which is no longer produced. As far as I can tell, Atlas V rockets are not as powerful and would not be able to deliver the lunar lander to the surface of the Moon.

If we were to launch another Apollo mission to land on the Moon today, do we have a rocket powerful enough to do it?

Comment: I wonder, with the advances of technology, how much weight could be shed from the lander as well.

Comment: @SF. That's a good question in itself. I doubt there's much more to do in that direction. While robots can be miniaturized, humans have a fixed size and mass and need equipment at similar scale.

Comment: @LocalFluff: electronics, batteries and solar panels moved ahead by strides. OTOH fuel, engines and structural parts didn't, not much to be gained here.

Comment: If he doesn't need to come back, then sure.

Comment: @SF: You'd be mistaken about the structural parts. Modern composite materials are significantly lighter.

Comment: The majority of the weight is always going to be propellant, so by Amdahl's Law there's not that much room for weight optimization.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: I still wonder what part of the propellant is used for translunar transfer there and back: we have our shiny new ion engines nowadays, though both landing and the two orbital injections still must run on chemical rockets.

Comment: You'd spend much more in consumables and radiation shielding than you'd save in fuel if you went to ion engines; SMART-1 took fourteen months to get to lunar sphere of influence. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMART-1

Comment: @RussellBorogove doesn't the weight of propellant roughly scale with the weight of the thing being propelled? If lander decreases by 20%, shouldn't to first order, lander's propellant decrease by roughly that as well?

Comment: Yes, but I was more thinking that there just isn't that much structural mass in the Apollo LM design, so there's less low-hanging fruit to optimize away. (Besides, mass increase from additional features will probably outstrip any mass savings from modern technology.)

Comment: Do it sensibly, with multiple launches assembling modules in LEO.

Comment: @MarkAdler It's even easier if a soft landing is not required

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the questions wording you mean, could we lift the Apollo CM/LM stack on any existing boosters? In that case no. Largest heavy lift vehicle is probably Delta-4-Heavy.  Falcon Heavy is not yet operational and will exceed it, but has a low Isp upper stage so is not optimal for such missions.

Could a different moon mission be launched? Almost certainly, just a matter of launching in smaller pieces and likely refueling in orbit. Would it be worth it? Well clearly no one has thought it worthwhile to date.

You would launch something like the Command Module and Service module (In one or two modules), where the Service module would act as an upper stage, and then refuel it in orbit from following launches. Then another launch for a Lunar Module, assemble in orbit and onwards.

There is a lot of speculation that the Falcon Heavy demo payload might be an Apollo 8 style mission, where a capsule is sent to go around the moon and come back.

If there was a true desire to do so, it is likely possible, but no one has decided it is necessary.

Additionally, consider costs. A Saturn V in modern dollars has been estimated in \$2 billion dollar range a launch. A Delta 4 Heavy is around \$400 million a launch.  A Falcon Heavy launch is advertised at \$125 million. (Assuming they ever develop cross feed). Thus even 5 Delta 4 Heavy launches is competitive with a Saturn V, and as many as 16 Falcon Heavy launches.

With the experience of building the ISS a lot of technology and tools for in space assembly has become much more feasible than in the 1960s on a tight deadline.

We probably no longer need a giant super booster just for the moon, even though SpaceX plans to build one as the BFR/MCT combo for Mars missions.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but prior to the development of the Saturn V rocket, wasn't Werner von Braun's initial idea to sent components for the Moon missions into Earth orbit, have them assembled there before sending the combined package to the Moon? The plan was changed once someone from one NASA contractors revealed the expense of such a system compared to launching a complete package using just one rocket.

Comment: @Fred : http://www.universetoday.com/63758/13-things-that-saved-apollo-13-part-12-lunar-orbit-rendezvous/

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking. All the talk about returning to the Moon, building Moon village, etc, got me thinking if we even have the ability to put a man on the Moon, something we did 50 years ago. It seemed to me that the easiest way to answer that is to see if we can redo the Apollo missions.

Comment: @Fred: Back then orbital rendezvous was in its infancy and so was steamlined production of launchers. I'm fairly sure we could launch segments of Apollo lander and command module and assemble them in orbit today cheaper, than a Saturn V launch costs.

Comment: To redo Apollo you need a single 140-ton-to-LEO launcher; if you're going to do an Earth orbit assembly of multiple launches you may as well throw the entire Apollo playbook and start over from scratch. In any case, the growth of bureaucracy in both NASA and congress guarantees that there's no way a moon mission would be cheaper today (even inflation-adjusted) than in the past. (And I'm not even cynical.)

Comment: @Fred: You're correct, von Braun did have some really cool ideas regarding space exploration. Be sure to watch the super-excellent Disney educational film dealing with this subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZImSTxbglI

Comment: Isn't there a huge speed difference between orbital speed and escape velocity? How would they overcome it if they assemble everything in Earth orbit?

Comment: @vsz Same way the Apollo stack was sent from a very low LEO staging orbit to the moon. Part of the stack (Saturn IVB third stage in that case) does the burn to provide the energy to get there.

Answer (score 6):

No. But two ideas about how to do it aren't far off, although I doubt it will be done that way.

- Falcon Heavy, which would be three Falcon 9 first stages put together
  and which will test fly in September 2016 (if not postponed again and
  again). It would require [two launches](http://shitelonsays.com/transcript/spacex-next-falcon-heavy-press-conference-2011-04-05). One that lands an empty ascent
  and return vehicle on the Moon, and a second which lands an astronaut
  or two next to it.
- Russian Angara 5, which would be the heaviest launcher in the world today and has been successfully [test launched](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/angara5_flight1.html) in 2014, but in a yet uncomplete configuration, has officially been proposed to send kosmonauts to the Moon with [four launches](http://sputniknews.com/russia/20151029/1029277505/russia-moon-mission-angara.html) that assemble the lunar mission in low Earth orbit.

Comment: you'd best hit bull's eye on that second launch!

Comment: @njzk2: "Houston to moon mission: you've got legs haven't you? Well then less talking more walking."

Comment: @SteveJessop Talking consumes precious oxygen.

Answer (score -3):

I remember reading in [Bill Bryson's - a short history of nearly everything](http://www.billbryson.co.uk/index.php/a-short-history-of-nearly-everything/) that we no longer possess a rocket powerful enough to send a man to the moon! Apparently the historic Apollo 11 plans were destroyed sometime in 90's by NASA during a spring clean.

Comment: That is incorrect. NASA retains piles and piles of documentation on the Saturn V and other Apollo hardware.

Comment: Even if true, NASA destroying the plans is not that big of a deal. There are most likely largely obsolete, after all it's been 50 years.

Comment: See this Q&A for why the existence of the Saturn/Apollo plans is irrelevant: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6281/why-not-build-saturn-vs-again

Comment: @Hobbes: Besides, we've still got at least one complete Saturn V on display somewhere that could be reverse-engineered if necessary.