# Will the countries ever co-operate again for the next upcoming era of Martian exploration?

Tags: mars, nasa, roscosmos, space-agencies

In the beginning of space exploration, there was sort of a Space Race between the United States and Soviets in order to achieve something bigger to dominate over one another. But after a matter of time, both the countries decided to end the competition and co-operate together for better results and the most magnificent example is the ISS.

Since, nearly all the space agencies are setting up their slingshot for Mars, I can feel a similar upcoming race or competition in the Martian Exploration e.g. Elon Musk. Are there any possible chances that all the organisations will again co-operate together to add better results in the Martian Exploration, will it be economically and scientifically better to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely the countries will eventually cooperate when it comes to Mars, *after the Mars race*.

**Plans to go to Mars.**
The details of when and where are not clear. China wants to go to Mars by the end of *2020*. Whilst Obama stated that the United States will go to Mars in the 2030s. As for private companies, SpaceX wants to go there and are making the most headway. Blue Origin wants to put a human on both the Moon and Mars. *It's just a more passive space race.*

**The big competitors.** For right now, the main competitors are *NASA*, *SpaceX* and *Blue Origin*. In the 1960s when the USSR and the USA were competing, it was between nation-states. Many experts say that the Mars race is going to be between private companies and NASA. *Considering the private companies need money from contracts, they're competing, not joining forces.*

**Who's further?** This is debatable. *In my opinion,* NASA is ahead. NASA has manned flight (and manned landings) experience from Gemini, Mercury, and of course, Apollo. NASA also still has the powerful rockets, with the Saturn V rocket and the SLS Block 1. NASA also has also traversed to Mars and planted rovers on the surface.

Comment: This is a nicely written answer, but the question will probably be closed because it is primarily opinion-based. You worked hard to answer an existing question here and that's great! But in the future you'll find that answers which aren't backed up with verifiable facts may not be so well received. In any event, welcome to stackexchange! And if you haven't already, you can [take the tour](https://space.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: I appreciate the remembrance and the gracefulness @uhoh glad to be here :D

Comment: Regarding NASA's Saturn V, you may be interested in [Do we still have all the blueprints to go to the Moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21657/415) and [Why not build Saturn V's again?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/6281/415) and [Were the Saturn V construction plans destroyed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20302/415) which all discuss, to varying extent and from different perspectives, the issues surrounding building new Saturn V rockets based on the old design.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Well obviously, but NASA still has the experience with the Saturn V. It has already resolved the kinks with lunar exploration.