# How many good days per year Cape Canaveral has?

Tags: launch, statistics

On average, how many days per year have good enough weather for a space rocket launch (not ICBM) at Cape Canaveral?

Comment: What kind of rocket? They have different limits. Naval ICBMs launched from there had pretty wide weather rules. The shuttle, not so much.

Comment: No ICBM space launches

Comment: No spy satellites or military comsats? Please define your requirements in the question.

Comment: Sorry I corrected now. Military and spy satellites are fine, ICBM not

Comment: @OrganicMarble good point! [Do smaller rockets require better weather at launch than larger ones?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24548/12102)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This table shows that for the 494 launch countdowns between October 1988 and August 2000 at the Eastern Test Range, there was a 10% chance of a weather related delay and an 18% chance of a weather related scrub.

[image]

Source: [Weather Support to the Space Shuttle: An Historical Perspective](https://ams.confex.com/ams/pdfpapers/85962.pdf)

Comment: Is there în that interval a season or a month with significantly less planned launches? That would imply such times are worse