# Do we still have all the blueprints to go to the Moon?

Tags: the-moon, crewed-spaceflight, nasa

The answer to [Do we still have all the equipment to go back to the moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21651/do-we-still-have-all-the-equipment-to-go-back-to-the-moon) is an unambiguous "no". Most of the equipment went to museums or got scrapped. But do we still have all the know-how?

Say, a political miracle happens, and the Congress decides "Apollo 18 should happen ASAP" and it should be an exact duplicate of Apollo 17. No R&D work is expected, just rebuilding the Apollo 17 from scratch. Rebuild/restart all the manufacturing, reopen all the closed facilities, all the engineering work to get it all up and running basing on existing documentation, training based on old procedures, astronauts training on equipment rebuilt from old blueprints, zero new research. If contractors / 3rd party manufacturers no longer produce something, they'll be paid to reopen the production, rebuilding production facilities and retraining the crew if needed, but not "reinvent" the technology if it was lost.

Do we have all the data to do this, or was some of it lost, say, passed as word-of-mouth and forgotten, or destroyed along with closure of some facilities?

As for the duplicate suggestion, the gist of difference between the questions is: the Saturn one asks "Why don't we", with answer "We don't want to - It's not practical." Mine asks "But *can we*, assuming we'd (somehow) want to and had the budget?"

Comment: Building the flight computers for CM and LM just the same way is not reasonable. The days of core rope memories and low scale integration chips are long ago. The necessary high reliability of the electronic parts is not achievable by producing only the parts necessary for one mission. There are better methods now to build the combustion chambers and nozzles of the rocket engines by welding a lot of tubes.

Comment: I like the question, but I'm having trouble envisioning a good answer.

Comment: @called2voyage: Hobbes' answer is already pretty good. If some essential procedures were undocumented and are forgotten, that would be it. Some specific examples would be great but if none appear, I'll approve his answer.

Comment: Note that, for almost any large project of almost any organisation, trying to do it again with only the written records and no staff continuity tends to be impossible without a substantial re-discovery/invention effort. There will be important stuff that was known only to oral culture and never written down. The Nimrod fiasco is a good example of this. I can see a "just rebuild Apollo" project wasting tens of billions of dollars and ultimately producing nothing workable, in exactly the same way.

Comment: Even if you had every blueprint and spec, many of the parts would not be available.  Look at the travails that the people trying to restore the Lunar Orbiter tapes went through.  "The only working version of the Ampex tape player ($300K when new) was discovered in a chicken coop and restored with the help of the original designer. There is only one person on Earth who still refurbishes these tape heads, and he is retiring this year. The skills to read this data archive are on the cusp of disappearing forever."  http://www.thelivingmoon.com/47john_lear/02files/Lunar_Orbiter_Tapes_Found.html

Comment: @OrganicMarble Well, that's just called transferring everything over to new databases and storage systems. I think the question is primarily interested in whether it is feasible for NASA to restore those plans and get them to a new computer system or cloud storage.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck -- Re "that's just called transferring everything" -- You used "just" there, which is possibly the most dangerous word in engineering. How do you transfer over data that is unreadable?

Comment: @David Hammen they said the data would be unreadable in a decade or two, not at this date and time. Also, I didn't say it would be easy, I said that they what they were describing is just transferring data. They were over complicating their post. It would be far simpler to just say that we cannot transfer the old documents as the readers no longer exist. Also, the word "just" isn't a dangerous word. It's a filler word that has literally 0 meaning in a sentence. I write it there because it sounded good in terms of sentence flow... -_-

Comment: "Can we?" is a largely irrelevant question given that there would be no benefit to a lunar mission using technology from 50 years ago. Apart from the economics of manufacturing all the specialized components the way they did 50 years ago because of the limitations which existed 50 years ago, there is the safety aspect. Even though it was designed with sufficient safety/redundancy to maximize the likelihood of a successful outcome, the crew risks accepted back then would likely be unconscionable today. To go back to the Moon requires a more modern solution.

Comment: For all the gaps which may exist in the technical records from the Apollo era, there is still a lot of useful knowledge and wisdom from back then to inform a return  to the Moon.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's a related question on the [Saturn V](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20302/were-the-saturn-v-construction-plans-destroyed/20306#20306) which addresses some of your question.
In general, it's difficult to document a complicated system so thoroughly that there will be no surprises at all when you rebuild from the documentation. Blueprints are one thing, but most of the parts of a Saturn V were handbuilt and needed minor adjustments during assembly. I doubt all of those were documented rigorously.

This was standard procedure back then. A recent example of how this can resurface and bite you in the ass is the [BAE Nimrod MRA.4 saga](http://www.aeroflight.co.uk/aircraft/types/type-details/bae-systems-nimrod.htm): the plan was to fit 1960-vintage aircraft with a new wing (in order to accommodate new engines). The new wing was designed in CAD based on measurements from one airframe. When they built the second new wing and tried to mate it to the second airframe, they found it didn't fit. The airframes were different.

The Apollo program had tens of thousands of subcontractors (from huge aerospace firms down to tiny mom-and-pop shops), many of which are long gone.

Comment: I suspect that almost all non-trivial changes were documented, but documentation has been lost.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that fiasco with the wings is part of why the program was cancelled and the UK ultimately decided to buy P8 Poseidon's instead?

Comment: The wing problems were solved, but the program was plagued by cost overruns. The cancellation was a political decision and came at a time when the aircraft were nearly finished.

Answer (score 8):

This is, of course, possible. For a very special meaning of the word "possible": extremely ***expensive***, ***dangerous*** (to the astronauts), and ***pointless***.

This question reminded me of the [Tu-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-4) - the Soviet reverse-engineered copy of the American-made [Boeing B-29 Superfortress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-29_Superfortress). Stalin had 3 B-29 which emergency-landed in the USSR during WW2, and he ordered [Tupolev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev) to copy them. This turned out to be a **brilliant** step: copying the plane (as opposed to creating a "better version suitable to the existing Soviet realities") required creating whole new industries and gave a huge boost the the Soviet aircraft technology.

Copying Apollo would have the **opposite** effect: resurrecting obsolete technology instead of creating the new ones.

Suppose we want to repeat [Magellan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_Magellan)'s circumnavigation (yes, I know he died on the way). Would we build a modern ship to do that or re-create his caravels?

Comment: "Suppose we want to repeat Magellan's circumnavigation (yes, I know he died on the way). Would we build a modern ship to do that or re-create his caravels?" - Possibly a bad example, as there have been people who have recreated historical journeys, trying to recreate the original equipment as closely as possible. Maybe someday Apollo will be recreated in this manner as well. Probably not anytime soon, but you never know.

Comment: @called2voyage I bet those people still had modern boats or aircraft following behind for safety. +1

Comment: @called2voyage: the difference is we have a lot of great crafts capable of repeating Magellan's route.

Comment: @SF.: actually, we don't have non-nuclear craft capable of circumnavigation without refueling.

Comment: @sds: Are you sure that's beyond capabilities of oil tankers?

Comment: @SF. this is far beyond the topic at hand, but tankers usually don't "eat" their cargo (not that they cannot).

Comment: @sds Magellan's ships did not sail non-stop.  Food and water got picked up at regular intervals.

Answer (score 7):

This question is possibly too broad because there are many forms of "know-how". Also, how much of the past do you want to recreate?

One of the key skills that would have been lost are the manufacturing skills - on the shop floor and management of the manufacturing processes. If need be, that could be redeveloped. But would you want to recreate the factories and equipment of the 1950s and 1960s or use modern equipment in existing factories?

The other thing is, if you wanted to make a Saturn V rocket and the lunar module and the lunar rover would you want to use the same electrical and electronic systems. Do the transistors and computer chips of that era still exist. Would you want to recreate them from scratch or would you want to modernize the electronic systems with components currently available?

While on the subject of computers, what about computer software? Do you want to use the software of the late 1960s and early 1970s or would you prefer it to be re-written using computer languages that are currently being used? Would you prefer the software to do just want it did during the Apollo era or would you like it to be able to do a more than was possible back then? Do you want to be able to recreate the computer overflow error that occurred during the landing of Apollo 11 because too many devices were left switched on?

Comment: let's say if a drop-in modern replacement (as big and complex as you desire, e.g. a whole rocket engine, or as small, like a single transistor) is available, sure, go with it. But if integration were to involve developing more than a simple adapter to match the pins, or bolt locations, that would be a "no" and definitely not designing a new one. This is a rather abstract question - don't treat the example literally, but consider it as "how much of past knowledge is was lost?"

Comment: @SF I think the better question is; "how much past knowledge is now obsolete". I think everything regarding computers of that era is not that useful.

Comment: @Ajasja: It's a matter of difference: Obsoleted by newer, better, or lost to the past leaving only void behind?

Comment: @SF: well, you tell me https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_rope_memory :)

Comment: @Ajasja: Sure memory modules just *advanced*. But what about a thing like landing computers? Do we have a computer - and software for it - that could drive the RCS and engine of the lander to set it down gently - or would we need to - oh well, pick some Raspberry Pi or other Beaglebone and *write the software from scratch*?

Comment: I think it's worth noting that nearly every project NASA works on uses computer technology that's already 5 to 10 years old. AFAIK, Hubble, for example, was built using 286 computer systems and CPU's as they had already been tried and tested on earth, so they knew it would work. Same went for the Shuttle, which obviously increases maintenance work the older a ship gets, as those components get harder and harder to find.

Comment: The Apollo software is still around, IIRC you can find it and an emulator online. But that software was designed for very specific hardware. If you ran it in an emulator on modern hardware, you'd have to space-qualify the emulator. It might be easier to borrow landing software from SpaceX and adjust its parameters.

Comment: Why should we use computers for flight control of CM and LM being so slow, with very small memories for programm and data and with a very simple display for only a few decimal digits? We could build a smaller computer with less weight, less power consumption and much less parts and better reliability but more speed and much more memory.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80286

Comment: @FelixDombek that's a 16 bit computer system then, not a 286 computer system!

Comment: @TheGreatDuck it's clearly both, but 286 is more specific, it names the exact processors used. There were lots of 16 bit processors back then that had different instruction sets and pin configurations, so the processor determined the whole system.

Comment: @FelixDombek but "# system" indicates the number of bits and not the model of processor. That's the convention so calling it a 286 system makes it sound like a 286 bit system.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Nope, that's not usually the case. You don't omit “bit“. If there's no “bit“ then sth else is meant. I might have a x86 system for example.

Comment: @Typhon AFAIK there has never been a 286 *bit* processor, or any plans to make one.  (A *256 bit* processor, certainly, but not a *286 bit* one.)  IBM called the PC model they released in 1986 the "[XT 286](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Personal_Computer_XT)" because it had an 80286 processor in it, so the "286 computer" meme became part of the culture.  If you do a Web search for "286 computer" you will find lots of information about this *16 bit* type of machine "everybody" calls a "286 computer"

Comment: @FKEinternet I never said there was such a system. I was saying the name sounded deceptive to me.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck It might have because you're not familiar with the system. It was a common, popular name and it wasn't deceptive to anyone at the time the platform was in widespread use.It's like saying the name Windows 95 is deceptive because it wasn't the 95th release of the system.

Answer (score 5):

**No**

The Apollo missions were huge, custom built machines made in very small quantity built on the cutting edge of what was possible.  Presumably much of the required infrastructure was shut down and or made obsolete.

Even if we had the exact specs for every part, and the specs on how to make the machines that make that part (so on and so forth), we no longer have the people that made it possible.  If a single engineer, welder, QA tester, supplier (or so on) has even one slightly different interpretation of a task than anticipated it could end in failure.

SpaceX's recent failure due to a strut comes to mind... and that was the same company, building the same rocket with the same team using the same supplier.

**Think of it as making a cake**... involving tens of thousands of people... decades later... with different training and tools... where any single minor change could end up as RUD.  I don't care how could good recipe is... I'm not baking that.

Comment: Define RUD please ?

Comment: Rapid Unscheduled Disassembly, i.e. an explosion.

Comment: Forget about the act of *baking* the cake... would you *eat* it? (Something like: get into the cockpit and trust your life to that the thing doesn't blow up the first chance it gets.)

Comment: @Hobbes That has to be one of the most pretentious ways of referring to an explosion I have ever seen. Pardon me, but such elitist slang just cannot resist caricature. Anyone using such slang makes me think of someone who unironically refers to him/herself in third person.

Answer (score 2):

Every single aspect involved new engineering. I worked on the ablative heat shield, doing just one small corner of the testing. We were constantly trying new combinations of materials. All that work would need to be re-created with newer methods.

It *IS* rocket science. Study the history of rocketry, where the difficulty is to get predictable behavior out of hypergolic chemistry. Look up the term hypergolic chemistry. There are some neat videos, including the film of the lunar lander taking off from the moon.

Comment: Oh, I know of the trials and tribulations of *getting there*. But for hypergolic chemistry, there is no longer any need to test a thousand substances; you *know* you need RFNA at 98.5% sharp, add HF to make up 5%, mix hydrazine with UDMH in 20-55% proportions - this all is *documented*. Years of work and billions of dollars resulted in some concise documents that mean every smallest lab, as long as it has the right security clearances, can make the hypergolic fuels needing just a couple calls to chemical suppliers, and at cost not exceeding the cost of substrates by much.

Comment: *"We were constantly trying new combinations of materials. All that work would need to be re-created with newer methods."* Isn't the outcome of all that work exactly the kind of information that would *be* in the final blueprints and other relevant engineering documentation?